# ImageButton.Click event works with 1 Label rendered on top of it but not 2 Labels

Tags: c#, .net, maui, maui-windows

This appears to be an issue when running in Windows (haven't tested any other platform yet):

I have a single row & single column Grid with an ImageButton inside of it.

I then added a Label in the Grid so that it renders on top of the ImageButton. So far so good, the Click event works on the ImageButton.

I add one more Label to the same Grid after that, so it renders on top of the other Label, and on top of the ImageButton, and the Click event stops working. What gives?

---

The purpose of this UI is for a Scrabble game I'm making. This particular element is the tile which is an ImageButton with the appropriate background color, the first Label for the letter, and the second Label for the value of that letter. Example:

[image: Scrabble Tile]

---

Code:

```
// BoardCell.cs Class for the Scrabble Letter Tile
public class BoardCell : StackLayout
{
    public ImageButton TileImageButton { get; private set; }
    public Label TileLetterLabel { get; private set; }
    public Label TileValueLabel { get; private set; }

    public BoardCell(Enums.BoardCellTypes boardCellType)
    {
        // Setup the TileImageButton
        TileImageButton = new ImageButton();
        TileImageButton.WidthRequest = 80;
        TileImageButton.HeightRequest = 80;
        TileImageButton.BorderColor = Colors.DarkGray;
        TileImageButton.BorderWidth = 2;

        // Setup the Tile Grid
        var tileGrid = new Grid();
        tileGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = GridLength.Star });
        tileGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = GridLength.Star });

        // Add the Tile Image Button
        tileGrid.Children.Add(TileImageButton);
        Grid.SetRow(TileImageButton, 0);
        Grid.SetColumn(TileImageButton, 0);

        // Setup and add the Tile Letter Label
        TileLetterLabel = new Label();
        TileLetterLabel.TextColor = Colors.Black;
        TileLetterLabel.FontSize = 48;
        TileLetterLabel.FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold;
        TileLetterLabel.HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
        TileLetterLabel.VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
        TileLetterLabel.IsVisible = false; // Important this is initially false, otherwise it blocks clicks on the TileImageButton behind it

        tileGrid.Children.Add(TileLetterLabel);
        Grid.SetRow(TileLetterLabel, 0);
        Grid.SetColumn(TileLetterLabel, 0);

        // Setup and add the Tile Value Label
        TileValueLabel = new Label();
        TileValueLabel.TextColor = Colors.Black;
        TileValueLabel.FontSize = 12;
        TileValueLabel.FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold;
        TileValueLabel.HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
        TileValueLabel.VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.End;

        tileGrid.Children.Add(TileValueLabel);
        Grid.SetRow(TileValueLabel, 0);
        Grid.SetColumn(TileValueLabel, 0);

        // Add the tileGrid to the StackLayout of this control
        this.Children.Add(tileGrid);

        if (boardCellType == Enums.BoardCellTypes.TileLetter)
        {
            SetTileValueLabel();
            TileLetterLabel.IsVisible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            TileLetterLabel.IsVisible = false;
        }
    }

    public void SetTileValueLabel()
    {
        this.TileValueLabel.Text = this.TileValue.ToString();
    }
}
```

---

```
// MainPage.xaml.cs
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    BoardCell SelectedTile { get; set; }

    public MainPage()
    {
        BoardTileTapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
        BoardTileTapGestureRecognizer.Tapped += BoardTileTapGestureRecognizer_Tapped;

        InitializeBoard();

        MyTileTapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
        MyTileTapGestureRecognizer.Tapped += MyTileTapGestureRecognizer_Tapped;
    }

    private void BoardTileTapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      // Does a bunch of stuff, but this event doesn't fire with this bug
    }

    private void MyTileTapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // This one does fire
        SelectedTile = GetBoardCellParent(sender); // Sets the SelectedTile to clicked on BoardCell object
    }
}
```

---

```
private void InitializeBoard()
{
    for (int row = 0; row <= 14; row++)
    {
        // Setup new row and column for gameboard (only need to do this 15 times for each for a 15x15 grid)
        var tileRowDefinition = new RowDefinition() { Height = 80 };
        var tileColumnDefinition = new ColumnDefinition() { Width = 80 };

        grid_GameBoard.RowDefinitions.Add(tileRowDefinition);
        grid_GameBoard.ColumnDefinitions.Add(tileColumnDefinition);

        for (int column = 0; column <= 14; column++)
        {
            // Create a new board cell and set it's clicked event
            BoardCell boardCell = GetNewBoardCell(row, column);
            boardCell.TileImageButton.Clicked += OnBoardCellClicked;
            boardCell.TileLetterLabel.GestureRecognizers.Add(BoardTileTapGestureRecognizer);

            // Add the new board cell to the grid                
            grid_GameBoard.Children.Add(boardCell);
            Grid.SetRow(boardCell, row);
            Grid.SetColumn(boardCell, column);
        }
    }
```

---

```
private void OnBoardCellClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Does a few things but never gets hit with this bug
}
```

---

```
// MainPage.xaml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ScrabbleMaui2.MainPage">

    <ScrollView>
        <!--<Grid RowSpacing="25" RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,*"
              Padding="{OnPlatform iOS='30,60,30,30', Default='30'}">-->

        <Grid x:Name="grid_Game" RowDefinitions="50,*,100" ColumnDefinitions="*" MaximumHeightRequest="1500">
            <Grid x:Name="grid_TitleBar" Grid.Row="0" ColumnDefinitions="*,*,*">
                <Grid x:Name="grid_Score" ColumnDefinitions="*,*">
                    <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="My Score: " />
                    <Label x:Name="lbl_MyScore" Grid.Column="1" Text="0" />
                </Grid>

                <Button x:Name="btn_SubmitPlay" Grid.Column="2" Text="Play Word" WidthRequest="100" Clicked="btn_SubmitPlay_Clicked" />
            </Grid>

            <Grid x:Name="grid_GameBoard" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10" HorizontalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="Green" />

            <Grid x:Name="grid_MyTiles" Grid.Row="2" RowDefinitions="Auto" ColumnDefinitions="*,*,*,*,*,*,*" MaximumWidthRequest="620"
                  BackgroundColor="Blue" />
        </Grid>
    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>
```

---

---

Per ToolmakerSteve's suggestion, I re-arrange the controls I'm using to build my Tile object. I now place a transparent button last, so it's rendered as the top most element. This is the new code in the BoardCell.cs constructor:

```
public BoardCell(Enums.BoardCellTypes boardCellType, bool isCenterCell)
{
    this.IsLocked = false;
    this.BoardCellType = boardCellType;
    this.IsCenterCell = isCenterCell;

    var tileGrid = new Grid();
    tileGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = GridLength.Star });
    tileGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = GridLength.Star });

    TileBackground = new Image();
    TileLetterLabel = GetLetterLabel();
    TileValueLabel = GetValueLabel();

    SetTileBackground();
    SetTileValueLabel();

    TileButton = new Button();
    TileButton.WidthRequest = 80;
    TileButton.HeightRequest = 80;
    TileButton.IsVisible = false;

    tileGrid.Children.Add(TileBackground);
    tileGrid.Children.Add(TileLetterLabel);
    tileGrid.Children.Add(TileValueLabel);
    tileGrid.Children.Add(TileButton);

    Grid.SetRow(TileBackground, 0);
    Grid.SetRow(TileLetterLabel, 0);
    Grid.SetRow(TileValueLabel, 0);
    Grid.SetRow(TileButton, 0);

    Grid.SetColumn(TileBackground, 0);
    Grid.SetColumn(TileLetterLabel, 0);
    Grid.SetColumn(TileValueLabel, 0);
    Grid.SetColumn(TileButton, 0);

    this.Children.Add(tileGrid);
}
```

I'm now using a separate `Image` element as the background, and a regular `Button` element to be clicked on. Unfortunately I still exhibit the same behavior, oddly. The button's `Click` event doesn't fire as long as the `TileValueLabel` is added as a child to the `Grid`. If I comment out the lines that add it to the `Grid` - `tileGrid.Children.Add(TileValueLabel);` then `Click` event fires.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve The issue exists in both MAUI and Xamarin.Forms. I'll update my Post with example code when I'm back in front of my computer. Thanks.

Comment: can you post the requirement of your UI, can suggest better approach

Comment: @HimanshuDwivedi Please see my update with the requirement of the UI.

Comment: Set InputTransparent on the Labels

Comment: @Jason good suggestion, but that didn't seem to make any difference unfortunately.

Comment: still waiting on you to post the relevant code/xaml

Comment: @Jason will do, sorry, didn't have more than a minute this morning to test your suggestion. Will be able to add the code on my lunch break in a few hours. Will keep you posted.

Comment: @J.D. - you added `InputTransparent="True"` to both labels?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Yes. Tried every combination of setting it to `True` for both, or only one or the other Label. None of it seemed to matter. It's interesting that the ImageButton only stops working with 2 Labels rendered on top of it. Sorry I got stuck at work, promise to add the actual code tonight.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I've updated the Post with my code. Please don't mind the jankiness of it, it still needs to be refactored.

Comment: @Jason I've updated the Post with my code. Please don't mind the jankiness of it, it still needs to be refactored.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like there is a bug with passing input through multiple elements.

Try wrapping the two labels in a second grid, with InputTransparent on that inner grid:

```xml
<Grid ..>
  <ImageButton ../>
  <Grid InputTransparent="True">
    <Label ../>
    <Label ../>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I modified my code behind to mimic this suggestion, but it didn't seem to make a difference unfortunately. It's extra weird, because I re-use the `BoardCell` control in two places, and only one place the click event isn't firing: 1. The tiles the current player has, and 2. The board cell's themselves that get clicked on to drop the selected tile into. In the first use case, the `MyTileTapGestureRecognizer_Tapped` event fires, but for the second use case, neither the `BoardTileTapGestureRecognizer_Tapped` event or `OnBoardCellClicked` click event fire. Same object in both use cases though.

Comment: You could put a transparent button (no next no image) on top of everything else. So it receives the click.

Comment: That's a pretty solid idea. I'm used to WPF where it makes sense to embed controls inside each other (e.g. a Label inside a Button), but I like that idea. I'll give it a shot and will let you know.

Comment: So I tried this idea. I think it helped clean up some of the code in the process too. Unfortunately I experience the same exact behavior, even though the `Button` is now the top-most element in the children of the `Grid`. As long as the `TileValueLabel` is added to the stack, the `Click` event of the `Button` doesn't fire. Latest code added to the end of the Post.

Comment: Also, oddly, if I set the `Button.IsVisible = true;` then it also fixes the problem (but now you can't see the `Label`s behind it obviously).

Comment: I think I fixed my problem by using `TapGestureRecognizer`s instead of the `Click` event and basically eliminated the need for a `Button` at all. The `TapGestureRecognizer` is an event directly on the `BoardCell` object I created (I guess inherited from `StackLayout` or a parent object). I appreciate your help in any case! :)